# A question on the area of the unit disc w.r.t. a complete conformal metric

Tags: cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry

Question: Let $\Delta$ be the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\rho(z)|dz|^2$ be a complete conformal metric on $\Delta$ where $\rho(z)$ is continuous on $\Delta$.  Let $a$  be the infimum of $p (p>0)$ such that 
$\iint_\Delta |\rho(z)|^pdxdy=+\infty.$

I guess that $a\leq 1$.  Of course, generally $a$ depends on the complete metric $\rho(z)$. 
For example, w.r.t. the Poincare metric, $a=\frac{1}{2}.$ Also, one may consider the infimum of $a$.

Note. We only assume that $\rho(z)$ is continuous and  complete on the unit disc.

Comment: Is $a$ equal to $p$?

Comment: I encounter some problem in editting, e.g. \{\}, \frac{1}{2}

Comment: Your $a$ depends on the metric. 

Comment: Yes, $a$ dependant on the metric, but for all complete metric, I belive $a \leq 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completeness implies that 
$$\int_{1/2}^1\sqrt{\rho(r,\theta)}dr=\infty$$
for all $\theta$.
So, for a complete metric,
$$\int_\Delta\sqrt{\rho}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{\rho(r,\theta)}rdrd\theta=\infty.$$
Thus $a\leq 1/2$.

For Poincare metric $\rho=1/(1-r^2)^2$, so
$\alpha=1/2$, and this is best possible.

Comment: Oh, the solution is so simple. I can never bilieve it.